# rticles templates do not compile

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, article

I tried to use the template in the rticles and I get the following error :

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment cslreferences undefined.
```

and that's no matter which template, I choose. 
When I look up the text file generated after running the code, I see the section that contained the article references has the same name "clsreferences". In changing that to the bibliography, the tex version was able to compile. I am trying to understand where the problem comes from and how to fix it so I can still use `rmarkdown` as I am too well versed in latex.

If I comment on the .bib file, the template is able to compile. So I imagine, this has to do with the way this rmd is translated to tex to be able to compile;

Any help will be useful.

Thanks in advance,
[Here is the last template I attempted](https://pastebin.com/UPw872rK)

and here's the error it sent:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment cslreferences undefined.

Execution halted
```

Comment: Hi! Please format your post to make it easier to read. Also take a look at [how to ask a good, reproducible R question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. For me the template compiles and there is no trace of an `cslrefernces` environment. Which pandoc version and TeX system do you use? can you post the `pandoc` command-line that should be visible before the LaTeX error appears?

Comment: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test10.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+tex_math_single_backslash-autolink_bare_uris --output test10.tex --self-contained --template /home/bbauzile/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rticles/rmarkdown/templates/elsevier_article/resources/template.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --lua-filter /home/bbauzile/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /home/bbauzile/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --filter /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pandoc-citeproc

Comment: Are you using pandoc version 2.8? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193797/.

Comment: @RalfStubner I am using *pandoc version 2.8.0.1* .  Just tried and it did not solve it.

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: @RalfStubner. I created a file name with the code : 
---
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newenvironment{cslreferences}%
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \everypar{\setlength{\hangindent}{\cslhangindent}}\ignorespaces}%
  {\par}
---
and inserted it after the session like this:
output: rticles::elsevier_article 
head-include: clreferences_silent.tex

Comment: I'm working on it: https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/260 Meanwhile, if you are using RStudio, there is no need to install Pandoc separately---the current version of RStudio bundles a lower version of Pandoc, which won't create this problem. If you have to install Pandoc by yourself, you may install Pandoc before 2.8 before I fix the problem in rticles.

Comment: There is no `header-include` standard YAML header. And `header-includes` expects literal LaTeX code. Something like `header-includes: \input{clreferences_silent}` should work.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks! 
Yes, that did it. Both template and a document that I am working on were able to compile.

Comment: @YihuiXie, I tried uninstall pandoc and compiling the template without the solution proposed by Ralf. And it still didn't compile. I am very grateful for the help and the work you guys are doing!

Comment: I have fixed https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/260. Please try `remotes::install_github('rstudio/rticles')`.